# Why are there null geometry lines after using the contour tool in Spatial Analyst?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, contour, null-geometry

A few months ago, I ran the [Contour](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/3d-analyst-toolbox/contour.htm) tool on two separate DEMs (one was smoothed and the other wasn't).  The contour interval was set to 1m.

Today, I noticed that there were several features created with NULL geometry.

I created a field called partCount and populated it with the following python expression:

```
!SHAPE!.partCount
```

and then I applied the following query to my dataset:

```
partCount =0
```

You can see, there are several features with no parts and zero length.

However, they did get an elevation value.

[image]

My question is: why would the Contour tool create features with null geometry?

Note: the DEMs did contain No Data areas, but I'm not yet convinced this is the cause of the null geometry.

I created the contours in ArcGIS 10.3.1.

Comment: Your interval is likely too close for the data and/or coordinate reference, so the coordinates have collapsed. Leaving out features would be wrong, so the isoline is represented, but geometry is not.